# vb.net serial IO not always working

Tags: vb.net

All,
I have a simple vb.net program. It simply turns a usb relay on or off.
This works without problem in realterm,
but only the "relay on" works inside vb.net.

Here is the code:

```
    Sub SendSerialData(ByVal data As String)
            ' Send strings to a serial port.


            Dim comport As New IO.Ports.SerialPort
            comport.PortName = ListBox1.SelectedItem
            comport.Parity = IO.Ports.Parity.None
            comport.StopBits = IO.Ports.StopBits.One
            comport.BaudRate = 57600
            comport.DataBits = 8
            comport.Handshake = IO.Ports.Handshake.None
            comport.WriteTimeout = 500
            comport.ReadTimeout = 500

            If Not (comport.IsOpen) Then
                comport.Open()
            End If
            ' data = either "relay on" + vbCR or "relay off" + vbCR
            comport.WriteLine(data)
            Thread.Sleep(2000)
            comport.DiscardInBuffer()
            comport.Close()
            comport.Dispose()


        End Sub
```

Thank you,

Russ